# CSS Bootclass to Google Translate

Tags: jquery, css

Can you add a css bootclass to google translate?

Is it possible to add a "dropdown" class to my google translate button using jQuery? https://jsfiddle.net/tgokbf5j/6/

I have tried `$("#google_translate_element").addClass("dropdown");`

Is it possible to overwrite the css of the google translate button or just add the dropdown class making it the priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a class whenever you click on the google translate button you could do this by adding the add class event to the function:

```
$('#google_translate_element').on("click", function () {
     $(this).addClass('red');
})
```

See example: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cjczhuon/)

Comment: You need to add some style to your css also. Did you also do that??